# Highest Common Factor and Euclidean Algorithm Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

If a positive integer F divides a certain positive integer M, 6 is the remainder. When F divides M+33, 4 is the remainder. Find all possible values of F.

I found 1 possible value for F, which is 7. In this case, M could equal 48. The only method I know is using guess and check, but it is not efficient and could leave out other possibilities. Please help me find all the other possible values for F. Also, how would you prove that there are no other possibilities besides these?

Thanks :)

Comment: $M=aF+6, M+33=bF+4$, then $F(b-a)=35\Rightarrow F$ divides 35.

Comment: so the possible values of F are 7 and all the multiples of 35?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first divisibility condition gives $$M=kF+6$$ for some integer $k$. Since the remainder is always less than the divisor so one must also have $6<F$. Similarly, the second divisibility condition gives $$M+33=sF+4\Rightarrow M=sF-29$$ with $4<F$ for some integer $s$. So $$kF+6=sF-29$$ This gives $$F(s-k)=35$$ with $F>6$ and therefore you get the possible values of $F$ as $7$ and $35$.

Comment: how did you get 35?

Comment: By equating $M$ from the first two equations.

Comment: So do you add 6 to 33 and then subtract that by 4 to get 35?

Comment: Does this mean M equals 35?

Comment: @Valerie I have added some details.

Comment: so the possible values of F are 5 and 7, right?

Comment: also, thank you for helping :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61462/discussion-between-valerie-and-pjk).

Comment: why would the numbers have to prime numbers? Couldn't F be 35?

Comment: Yes you are correct, $35$ is another possible value of $F$. In fact the previous answer was not entirely correct. See my updated answer @Valerie